# Save div hide option after refresh page

Tags: javascript, local-storage, browser-cache

can someone help me out. I want a alertbox at the top of the page. When i click on close, the div will close but after refresh it comes back.

How can i fix this ?

My code is:
**CSS**

```
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <strong>Alert:</strong> Close this bar, after refresh page this bar is not visibile.
</div>
```

Also add it on :

https://jsfiddle.net/fegeeez/d9yLamcg/2/

Comment: Is it a server-side rendered page or just a static html page?

Comment: servder-side page

Comment: you can use cookie or localStorage to store the state of popup in the current browser, running your website and make your logic to show alert only once, and can set the expiry time as well, for that you can use cookie option if you want to learn more about cookies in javascript try to learn from w3schools

Comment: Which backend or framework do you use? You need to use a flash session.

Comment: i will use it on magento

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to persist the state between two page loads. Once the user closes the alert store that information in cookies or in localStorage.

More info of both

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)